# imagine-svg - How to change SVG color with PHP Library?

Tags: php, svg

I am using imagine-svg for modifying size and getting the size of SVG image.
But there are way to colorize the SVG but nothing that guide to use that colorize method.

Following is my code.

```
$imagine = new Imagine();
$image = $imagine->open($svg_file);
$image->resize(new Box(300, 300));

// $image->effects()->colorize($image->palette(), array(255,0,0));

$image->save($file_path);
```

Any idea how can I change black svg image to red by using imagine-svg?

Thank you.

Using `$image->effects()->colorize($image->palette(), array(255,0,0));` leads me to following error

> Argument 1 passed to Contao\ImagineSvg\Effects::colorize() must be an instance of Imagine\Image\Palette\Color\ColorInterface, instance of Imagine\Image\Palette\RGB given, called in /var/www/html/site/public_html/wp-content/plugins/icon-svg-calculator/woo.php on line 369 and defined in /var/www/html/site/public_html/wp-content/plugins/icon-svg-calculator/vendor/contao/imagine-svg/src/Effects.php:83

**UPDATE**

REPLACED

```
// $image->effects()->colorize($image->palette(), array(255,0,0));
```

TO

```
$color_code = '#ff0000';
$image->effects()->colorize($image->palette()->color($color_code));
```

Comment: As the error says, you gave a Palette\RGB instance, but Palette\Color\ColorInterface is expected.